# How dryer machine works in india 240v

Tags: circuit-breaker, dryer, circuit

I took LG USA dryer to India. I know dryer runs on 240V thats why dryer has 2 hot (120v) lines (line1,line2, neutral,ground).

And in india by default electrical runs on 240v. So can I use line1 directly to 240v?

Please suggest me how to use?[image]

### Update:

I got 4KW 220v to 110V converter which can support dryer. I would like to connect Line1, Line2, Neutral and groud like this. Can gurus tell me will this idea works?

[image]

Comment: The problem is some parts(controls, clock, drive motor) expect 120 volts to work, 240 volts might fry them.  The heater will probably have no problem.  There might be something like a 240 to 120 volt transformer that has two 120 outputs.

Comment: Can you find a service manual for the *exact* model of dryer? That should have a wiring diagram in it, from which we could tell if it will run on 240 V or if it requires 120 V for some parts.

Comment: @AndrewMorton the wiring diagram is probably on a label on the back of the dryer

Comment: Your converter does not appear to be intended for this use, the wiring scheme you have guessed at is unlikely to work (can't be sure *what* that will do without the internal wiring diagram, possibly destroy itself faster) and is also far too small to run a dryer, so it's fairly certain to overheat and possibly catch fire, if it doesn't have overcurrent protection that trips first. And it does *nothing* for the wrong frequency. I stand by my prior advice.

Answer (score 8):

Taking a USA dryer to India was very probably a huge waste of time, effort and money.

The heating elements use 240V (Hot to Hot), but in most cases the motor, timer, controls etc. on USA models use 120V (Hot to Neutral) and in 240V-only countries you have only 240V Hot to Neutral so the dryer as a whole won't work.

If you connect line 1 and neutral, you'll fry the 120V parts and have no connection at the other end of the 240V parts.

The cost of replacing enough parts to make it work, (if you can even find those parts) is probably more than simply buying a dryer made to work on 240V-only and junking this one.

Comment: … aaand, it appears that India runs on 50hz, not the 60 the unit was designed for. This might mess with the sensitive electronics.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate -- the electronics would be much less of a worry than the motor for me

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Would you expect components designed for 120 V AC to last long enough on 240 V AC to not blow up before the user left the room? (The former may hasten the latter.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton -- depends on the stuff :P

Answer (score 4):

No. Dryers use a combination of 120V (for some loads) and 240V (for other loads).

Specifically, dryers use 120V for everything except the heating element.  The reason is, many dryers use natural gas for heat, and that allows common parts across both gas-fired and electric versions of the same dryer.

That is why **a dryer is NOT a 240V appliance**.  When an appliance has both 120V and 240V parts, it is called a 120V/240V appliance.

Your concept was doomed to failure. In the future, **do not haul electric appliances across oceans**. You may have been presuming that you can just "buy a power converter".  No. There is lots of junk sold online that pretends to be that, but does not work as a general purpose converter.  Legitimate ones are not consumer-affordable. It's a hard problem.

Someone with good electrical/electronics experience would be able to "hack" it to run.  The heating element could run straight off 220/230V - after all, it is just a dumb resistor.  However, *all the other stuff*, which fortunately are not large loads, will need 120V *and 60 Hz*, so a phase converter will be required sufficient for the tumble motor. Why 60 Hz? First the motor will take damage if you run it on the wrong frequency, and second *the timer* in the dryer is depending on 60 Hz to keep time.

Remember, dryers take a stupendous amount of power - 25 amps or so - far too much to plug into a random wall outlet. A special circuit is required.